# Wordpress woocommerce multiple orderby args loop

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, loops, woocommerce

Does anyone know how to incorporate a while loop into a basic order by filter? I have the following basic filter in my functions.php page that orders my products by the featured products and it works:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'am_woocommerce_catalog_orderby');
function am_woocommerce_catalog_orderby( $args ) {
    if(!$_GET['orderby']) {
        $args = array(
            'orderby'  => array( 'meta_value' => 'DESC' ),
            'meta_key' => '_featured'
        );
        return $args;
    }
}
```

My problem is I want to use some more advanced while loops to try and get multiple different arguments tied into the same args. I am trying to show my *featured products* first, then load that into an array then get my next loop and only show the products that are 6 months old or younger and add that to my array, then show everything else and sort them by menu_order and title and add it to my array as shown below:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'am_woocommerce_catalog_orderby');
function am_woocommerce_catalog_orderby( $my_post_array ) {
    if(!$_GET['orderby']) {
      //First loop - show featured
      $args['orderby'] = array( 'meta_value' => 'DESC' );
      $args['meta_key'] = '_featured';    

      $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
      while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
          $post_id = get_the_ID();
          $my_post = my_post_function($post_id);
          //Store the items in an array
          $my_post_array [] = $my_post;
          query_posts($args); 
      endwhile;
      wp_reset_query();

      //Second loop - Show newer than 6 months 
      $args = array(   
          'orderby' => 'date',
          'order' => 'DESC',
          'date_query' => array(
          array(
              'before' => '6 months ago',
              ),
          )
      );

      $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
      while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
          $post_id = get_the_ID();
          $my_post = my_post_function($post_id);
          //Store the items in an array
          $my_post_array [] = $my_post;
          query_posts($args); 
      endwhile;
      wp_reset_query();

      //Third loop - show everything else and sort by menu_order and title
      $args['orderby'] = array( 'menu_order' => 'ASC', 'title' => 'ASC' );

      $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
      while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
          $post_id = get_the_ID();
          $my_post = my_post_function($post_id);
          //Store the items in an array
          $my_post_array [] = $my_post;
          query_posts($args); 
      endwhile;
      wp_reset_query();

      //Remove duplicate entries from the array
      array_unique ( $my_post_array, SORT_STRING );

  }
}
```

Then the last thing I do is remove my duplicates. Only problem is it does not work and I am not sure where I am going wrong, I have not done something like this before so I could be working in the wrong area or missing something obvious. Anyone have ideas on how I can trouble shoot this or does anyone see something that may be causing me issues? Thanks for the help, still learning and trying to improve!